# Why is there no cut in Philip's hand?

Tags: rope

In the first scene of Rope (1948), Philip had a cut in his hand.

[image]

And in this scene there is no cut.

[image]

The main point of Rope (1948) is that the story happened in one day and in one day a human hand won't recover that fast. So why is there no cut in Philip's hand?

Comment: Because even Hitchcock is not immune to [goofs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040746/goofs#continuity)? Of course, if we want to overthink it, the whole concept here revolves around [making cuts invisible](http://www.openculture.com/2013/11/the-10-hidden-cuts-in-rope.html) to make the film seem like one continuous shot, so maybe Hitch was making a point of it there. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you’re missing an important scene. After the shot of the glass breaking, and before your other shot of no blood on his hands, there is a scene with Phillip putting direct pressure on his cut with a rag. This is just a small attention to detail Hitchcock provided us so we can see Phillip has addressed his wound.

[image]

I cut my hand on a broken glass when I was doing the dishes one time. Based on the water mixing with the blood, and the hand has many small blood vessels, it appeared to be bleeding profusely. After I held a paper towel on it (direct pressure) for a few min, it coagulated, and all that was left was a miniscule line where the cut was (barely noticeable). I always assumed that the same thing happened to Phillip, aside from the liquid being champagne and not water (like in my case).